# Why is java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection() still working after removing the SQLite database JAR?

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, jar

I'm having difficulties in Java with an SQLITE database provided in a separate JAR file.
Surprisingly, **the sqlite database seems to be accessed even after removing the JAR file, exiting and restarting the program** and even after rebooting the machine.

I'm using the Xerial driver `sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar` (for `org.sqlite.JDBC`).
**EDIT:** very same issue with `sqlite-jdbc-3.8.6.jar`.
Xerial JDBC driver is published here:
https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc

I'm really puzzled. Is there some kind of persistent cache for this particular JDBC driver? or is it something I missed regarding JDBC in general?

**CODE SAMPLE:**

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class SqliteJDBCTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection connection = null;
        Statement statement = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite::resource:jar:file:doesntexistJAR.jar!/doesntexistDB.sqlite");
            System.out.println("connection = " + connection);

            statement = connection.createStatement();
            System.out.println("statement = " + statement);
            rs = statement.executeQuery(" SELECT * FROM nonexistentTable WHERE key = 'nonexistentKey'");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                try {
                    connection.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above code sample shows the first step of the problem: on the first run, `DriverManager.getConnection(..)` throwed an exception as expected:

```
$ java -jar sqliteJDBCTest.jar 
java.sql.SQLException: failed to load jar:file:doesntexistJAR.jar!/doesntexistDB.sqlite: java.io.FileNotFoundException: doesntexistJAR.jar (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
    at org.sqlite.Conn.open(Conn.java:92)
    at org.sqlite.Conn.<init>(Conn.java:57)
    at org.sqlite.JDBC.createConnection(JDBC.java:77)
    at org.sqlite.JDBC.connect(JDBC.java:64)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
    at SqliteJDBCTest.main(SqliteJDBCTest.java:18)
```

But, since then, for each run I get the following output:

```
>java -jar sqliteJDBCTest.jar
    connection = org.sqlite.Conn@3fee733d
    statement = org.sqlite.Stmt@5acf9800
    java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table: nonexistentTable)
            at org.sqlite.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:383)
            at org.sqlite.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:387)
            at org.sqlite.DB.throwex(DB.java:374)
            at org.sqlite.NativeDB.prepare(Native Method)
            at org.sqlite.DB.prepare(DB.java:123)
            at org.sqlite.Stmt.executeQuery(Stmt.java:121)
            at SqliteJDBCTest.main(SqliteJDBCTest.java:23)
```

In this example, the `SQLException` "SQL error or missing database" is not the error we're expecting!

Not only is the database missing, but even the JAR file supposed to contain it!
So how come `getConnection()` doesn't throw an exception in the first place?

Comment: Have you tried inserting something into the Db and in a next attempt read it back? If this works the DB was created somewhere.

Comment: Yes, I have. Then, after removing the db I can still see what I inserted. N.B: I inserted manually, outside of my app, using an sqlite db editor from Sourceforge.

Comment: Well obviously the JAR file or another version of it is still available somewhere on the CLASSPATH.

Comment: But the JAR was properly removed from the filesystem. So I'm really puzzled.

Comment: Java has assured you that it has still found one. Keep looking.

Comment: Interesting post on the Xerial website: https://groups.google.com/forum/m/?fromgroups#!topic/xerial/Oayzj5nrJGk

Comment: Extract of the above post: "DB files will be extracted to a temporary folder (System.getProperty
("java.io.tmpdir"))." This could explain the persistence issue. As to the getConnection() issue, I filed a bug on the Xerial Jira interface.

Comment: @EJP You were close. The Xerial Sqlite JDBC driver doesn't find the JAR but a "temporary" copy of the database it created the first time `getConnection()` was called. The problem is this "temporary" copy is still there the next time(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: because of a bug in the Xerial JDBC driver.

When one requests the Xerial driver a connection by calling `DriverManager.getConnection(jdbc:sqlite::resource:jar:file:<local_location_of_JAR>!/<name_of_database_file>)`, **the driver creates a copy of the database file** on the temporary directory specified by the Java system property **`java.io.tmpdir`** and then operates on this copy.

The problem is that when the original JAR is removed, the driver loads the copy the next time(s) one uses the same `getConnection()` call. For me, this is a bug; the driver should at least check that the (possibly remote) JAR file pointed to by the URL is still there...

Second problem (the one described in the CODE SAMPLE of this post): when the original JAR file doesn't exist, a "*copy*" of the (non-existent) database is created, and the next time(s) `getConnection()` is called with the same parameters, the driver directly returns a phantom connection to this empty database that was never found...

I submitted this story in a bug report on the Xerial JIRA website:
https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/issue/158/drivermanagergetconnection-not-returning